# Trouble instantiating an object within an if block

Tags: java, scope

I've written a program where users can choose between two games to play: Pig or Snake. I tried to use the following code within my main method to create the appropriate kind of game:

```
if (gameType == 'p')
    PigGame game = new PigGame();
else
    SnakeGame game = new SnakeGame();
```

My compiler points to the second line and gives the error: `not a statement`

I have managed to fix the problem by writing an abstract class "Game" and then making PigGame and SnakeGame subclasses of it:

```
Game game;
if (gameType == 'p')
    game = new PigGame();
else
    game = new SnakeGame();
```

But I don't understand why the first construct didn't work. (I'm preparing to teach a high school programming course, but I'm new to Java and OOP so I can use any insights you can provide.)

Comment: did you import the PigGame and SnakeGame files? also, try not naming them the same var name…try using pigGame or snakeGame as your variable name...

Comment: Take a look at the following for some deeper understanding of the concept of block-scope in java: http://books.google.com/books?id=PbcWAAAAQBAJ&pg=PT212&lpg=PT212&dq=learning+java+understanding+block+scope&source=bl&ots=TIfEx409yS&sig=FjQTAyVKKQMSGDrQPz9oV1w_HW0&hl=en&sa=X&ei=dB0HUvX9CYb_yQG6j4CABA&ved=0CDoQ6AEwAg#v=onepage&q=learning%20java%20understanding%20block%20scope&f=false  Pay particular attention in the diagram to the places where it is indicated that variables go 'out-of-scope'.  Hope that helps.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that the scope of `game` is inside the if and the else

```
if (gameType == 'p')
    PigGame game = new PigGame();
else
    SnakeGame game = new SnakeGame();
```

So you can't use it anywhere else, that's why your second piece of code works.

Comment: Yes, that makes sense. I was fooled by the compiler error. It seemed that `PigGame game = new PigGame();` was a statement. I would have expected an error farther down when I tried to use game again.

Comment: @user2625004 I would recommend that you use the coding standard of always using braces with `for` and `if` statements in your class. It helps new programmers (or new Java programmers) to identify and catch issues like these and to build a good mental model of variable scope.

Answer (score 2):

"PigGame game = new PigGame();" is a declaration, not a statement. An if requires a statement, not a declaration. You could create a statement block containing it:

```
{
    PigGame game = new PigGame();
}
```

That would be syntactically correct. It would still be pointless, because game would be local to the statement block. You need game to be declared with a wider scope.

Answer (score 1):

It is actually a quite important issue

```
if (gameType == 'p')
    PigGame game = new PigGame();
else
    SnakeGame game = new SnakeGame();
```

does not compile only due to the Java grammar, which states that a variable declaration is not a statemant. In fact one could imagine a code, where he actually does not need this variable "game" and simply want to run constructors in if statement.

```
if (gameType == 'p')
    new PigGame();
else
    new SnakeGame();
```

and this will compile

```
if (gameType == 'p'){
    PigGame game = new PigGame();
}else{
    SnakeGame game = new SnakeGame();
}
```

this will also compile

Naturally in both cases - we do not have access to the variable outside the brackets, yet still, denying user to code it like

```
if (gameType == 'p')
    PigGame game = new PigGame();
else
    SnakeGame game = new SnakeGame();
```

is a bit arbitrary, and AFAIK aimed at making "sure" that user knows what he is doing. In general - score of variable is defined by its declaration surrounding brackets so if you write

```
{
Integer x=3;
System.out.println(x); //this works
}
System.out.println(x); //but this does not
```

and the same thing applies here - you can declare a `Game` object inside an if statement, but it would not be accseeible outside of it by the `game` variable. But it depends on your code, You could have something like

```
public class Game{
   public static Game lastCreatedGame;
   public Game(){
    lastCreatedGame=this;
   }
}
```

then, running

```
if (gameType == 'p')
    new PigGame();
else
    new SnakeGame();
```

would still give you access to the game, by `Game.lastCreatedGame` field

Answer (score 1):

This is the reason I request all newbies to not skip the curly braces because It gives a lot of clarity on scope.

When you make

```
if (gameType == 'p')
    PigGame game = new PigGame();
else
    SnakeGame game = new SnakeGame();
```

into

```
if (gameType == 'p') {
    PigGame game = new PigGame();
}
else {
    SnakeGame game = new SnakeGame();
}
```

the scope becomes clearer, both

`PigGame game = new PigGame();` and `SnakeGame game = new SnakeGame();`

only exist within their respective blocks (i.e) within their respective curly braces,

so that means you cannot use `game` anywhere outside of their respective blocks, the compiler sees this and throws an error to help you out.